# How to use usb speaker and built in audio speakers simultaneously on MAC OS X 10.6 using cocoa or anything else?

Tags: macos, usb

I asked this previously but [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) moved my question to superuser.com. I need a answer programmatically...

I want to use built in speakers and usb speakers simultaneously on MAC OS X 10.6.

I want to play different files on these (I do not want to play same file on both speakers).

Is it possible using cocoa (QTMovie or something else?) or anything else?

I have checked the  portaudio   thing but didn't get how this works! :(

I have also tried to send some data to the USB speakers but the sample "USBSimple Example" downloaded from apple's site didn't worked!

Comment: My answer is on superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/86778/how-to-use-usb-speaker-and-built-in-audio-speakers-simultaneously-on-mac-os-x-10/86781#86781

Comment: Thanks diciu, but i didn't get how portaudio works!! can you give me some sample code for how can i include this in my project..

Comment: portaudio does contain sample code (see the pa_tests directory in the portaudio distribution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I got it myself...

```
NSSound *airplaneSound = [NSSound soundNamed:@"Aura Cleanse-1.wav"];

[airplaneSound setPlaybackDeviceIdentifier:theCFString];
[airplaneSound play];
```

I can pass the audio device uid in the setPlaybackDeviceIdentifier to play this sound on a particular device

Please find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983984/how-to-get-audio-device-uid-to-pass-into-nssounds-setplaybackdeviceidentifier) how can you get audio device uid

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa has nothing to do with audio hardware management. If the features you need aren't in "Audio/MIDI Setup" and you don't understand the CoreAudio documentation, then there really aren't any other options for you beyond searching for a third-party product.

Comment: Thanks NSD, can you suggest any third party product for this... i tried portaudio but didn't get this to work...