# How to use a USB speaker and built-in audio speakers simultaneously on Mac OS X 10.6 using Cocoa or anything else?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, usb, audio

How to use a USB speaker and built-in audio speakers simultaneously on Mac OS X 10.6 using Cocoa or anything else?

I want to use the built-in speakers and USB speakers simultaneously on Mac OS X 10.6.

I want to play different files on these (I do not want to play same file on both speakers).

Is is possible using Cocoa or anything else?

Comment: This should be moved back to StackOverflow, AFAIK this is not that easy because Mac OS X is designed to only use _one_ speaker system at a time. For example sometimes it would be useful to have different audio output on the headphones than on the loudspeakers. Again AFAIK this is impossible with the standard plugs. (Using a USB one should work.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use usb speaker and built in audio speakers simultaneously on MAC OS X 10.6 using cocoa or anything else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969090/how-to-use-usb-speaker-and-built-in-audio-speakers-simultaneously-on-mac-os-x-10)

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically it's possible using a library like [portaudio](http://portaudio.com/) - you open two different streams (using Pa_OpenStream) and you get two different callbacks that you use to inject audio data.

I'm sure it's possible using Core Audio too, but that's more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

[Rogue Amoeba's Airfoil](http://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/) can redirect the audio stream from a single application to, f/ex, an Airport Express, leaving other audio to go the system speakers.  I don't have a USB audio device to test your specific application, but you can try it free.